# Как правильно делать периодические запросы, используя Sagas в React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, запрос, redux, redux-saga

Я пытался использовать **React Redux** в своем проекте, разобрался как делать асинхронные запросы используя `sagaMiddleware`. Представленный фрагмент кода запускается как раз с помощью `sagaMiddleware.run`. Все бы хорошо, да необходимо периодически опрашивать сервер, чтобы узнать появились ли данные или нет. Данные приходят в `data`, но `setTimeout` почему-то не срабатывает.
Вообще этот подход изучаю не долго. Может есть другие способы грамотно использовать паттерн **Redux** и делать ***периодические запросы*** к серверу?

```
import C from './constants'
import CONST from "../constants";
import {getDlgID} from "./reducers/chat";
import {getCliID} from "./reducers/users";
import {getDlgInfo, waitVol} from "./actions";
import {call, takeEvery, fork, put, select} from 'redux-saga/effects'


function* getDialogInfo() {
    const dlg_id = yield select(getDlgID);
    const cli_id = yield select(getCliID);
    const body = {
        dlg_id: dlg_id,
        msg_sendercliid: cli_id
    };

    try {
        const data = yield call(() => {
            return fetch(CONST.SERVER_HOST + 'getDialogInfo', {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }).then((res) => res.json());
        });

        if (data.interlocutor === null) {
            setTimeout(function* () {
                return yield put(getDlgInfo())
            },2000);
        } else {
            yield put(waitVol(false));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(waitVol(true));
    }
}

export default function* () {
    yield takeEvery(C.GET_DLG_INFO, getDialogInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, буквально через несколько минут как задал вопрос.
Почитал про генераторы [тут.](https://learn.javascript.ru/generator#biblioteka-co) Там как раз было решение моей проблемы. Крылось оно в 3 простых строчках:

```
yield new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
);
```

Как можно догадаться тут происходит таймаут на две секунды после чего я снова вызываю функцию генератор `getDialogInfo()` посредством вызова действия `yield put(getDlgInfo())`

Сейчас функция генератор, которая опрашивает сервер в ожидании собеседника выглядит так:

```
function* getDialogInfo(store) {
    const FUNC_NAME = "getDialogInfo()";
    console.log(FILE, FUNC_NAME, 'start');

    const show_chat = yield select(getShowChat);
    if (!show_chat) {
        console.log(FILE, FUNC_NAME, 'chat closed');
        return;
    }

    const dlg_id = yield select(getDlgID);
    const cli_id = yield select(getCliID);
    const body = {
        dlg_id: dlg_id,
        msg_sendercliid: cli_id
    };

    try {
        const data = yield call(() => {
            return fetch(CONST.SERVER_HOST + 'getDialogInfo', {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }).then((res) => res.json());
        });

        if (data.status !== 'OK') new Error('status don\'t OK');

        if (data.interlocutor === null) {
            console.log(FILE, FUNC_NAME, 'don\'t connected interlocutor');
            yield new Promise(
                resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
            );
            yield put(getDlgInfo())
        } else {
            // Собеседник подключился
            console.log(FILE, FUNC_NAME, 'connected interlocutor');
            let fullName = data.interlocutor.split(' ');
            let name = "Волонтер";
            if (fullName.length === 3) {
                name = fullName[1];
            }else {
                name = data.interlocutor;
            }

            yield put(addUser({name: name, role: data.role}));
            yield put(addSysMsg({text: 'Волонтер подключился к чату'}));
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // Ошибка при попытке запроса собеседника
        console.error(FILE, FUNC_NAME, err);

        yield put(addBtnMsgs({
            text: 'Не удалось выполнить поиск Волонтера. Попробуем еще?',
            buttons: [
                {
                    title: 'Да',
                    click: () => {
                        store.dispatch(addSysMsg({text: 'Запрашиваю волонтера...'}));
                        store.dispatch(getDlgInfo());
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Нет',
                    click: () => store.dispatch(
                        showChat({
                            show: false,
                        }),
                    )
                }]
        }));

    }
```

Comment: еще есть эффект delay

Answer (score 0):

Правильным было бы создать Channel. К примеру по экшну стартуем таймеры они постят в нужный канал события для начала запроса или делают запросы и кладут в канал результаты, отдельно и если нужно выгребая данные из канала ты решаешь обновить стор или бросить другой экшн через put в саге которая подписана на канал. По нужному экшну – тушим таймеры. Преимущество в том что не дергается петля redux все время (action->saga-middleware->reducer->connect functions).

Comment: Есть ли подходящий пример?